# Core Telephony framework ios 4.0

Tags: iphone

Hello can we add or show the view in core telephony framework. if possible then how? Actually i have two diffrent application, one for inbound, second for outbound, i need to do show one view after 5sec-10sec of call whether its incoming or outgoing.Please help me out and revert me back as soon as possible .  and its also a request please also send the reply to my gmail address i.e.goenka.sahil@gmail.com.
Really i need the code.

Answer (score 0):

Sahil, have a look at Siphon's source code @ http://code.google.com/p/siphon. In this code have a careful look at "RecentsViewController.mm". Hope this helps you.